# How to show each user´s data?

Tags: c#, database, webmatrix

I´ve made this webpage were a teacher can upload the marks to each student. After that, the teacher should be able to see a table of every student with its respected marks. My problem is that I can´t organize each mark to its respectfull student. It shows me every student and all the uploaded marks from every student repeated through.

Here is the webpage that displays the marks:

```
@{
 Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";

 var galleryId = UrlData[0].AsInt();
  var db = Database.Open("PhotoGallery");
   var subject = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Course FROM Subjects WHERE Sub_Id = @0", galleryId);
   var people = db.Query("SELECT * FROM UserProfiles WHERE Course = @0", subject.Course);
   var notas = "SELECT * FROM Notas INNER JOIN UserProfiles ON Notas.UserId = UserProfiles.UserId WHERE Notas.Sub_Id = @0";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

     <div class="aa_2 check">
    <div class="aa_3 check">

        <table class="check table_not">
            <tr class=" arrow2">
                <th>STUDENTS</th>
                <th>STUDENT´s MARK</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach(var users in people){
                <tr class="arrow">

                    <td>@users.Nombre @users.Apellido</td>
                    <td>
                    @foreach (var nott in db.Query(notas, galleryId)){
                        @nott.Nota
                    }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>


        </ul>
        </div>
         </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your nested foreach loop:

```
  @foreach (var nott in db.Query(notas, galleryId)){
     @nott.Nota
  }
```

looks like it runs through every mark in the db and prints it to the student's td. You need to use a where/if type statement to make it only print marks for that student. By the way your variable names are incomprehensible for some reason.

Comment: I know. You say that I have to use a where or if type statement... is it the same WHERE as the one used in the variable "notas"?

Answer (score 0):

Andrew is correct. Your notas sql is incorrect. Try the following.

Firstly change:

```
    var notas = "SELECT * FROM Notas INNER JOIN UserProfiles ON Notas.UserId = UserProfiles.UserId WHERE Notas.Sub_Id = @0";
```

To:

```
    var notas = "SELECT * FROM Notas WHERE Notas.UserId = @1 AND Notas.Sub_Id = @0"
```

Secondly change:

```
    foreach (var nott in db.Query(notas, galleryId)){
```

to:

```
    foreach (var nott in db.Query(notas, galleryId, users.UserId)){
```

I'm away from my dev machine at the moment so you may have to put an ampersand (@) in front of the users.UserId in that last foreach statement.